# Are the ring of power series and the ring of germs of holomorphic functions catenary?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, power-series

I am wondering if the following rings are catenary:

1. If $k$ is a field, is the ring of formal power series $k[[X_1,\dots,X_n]]$ catenary?
2. Is the ring of complex power series with a non-zero radius of convergence  $\Bbb C\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ (*id est* the ring of germs of holomorphic functions at zero) a catenary ring?

Comment: Until a few minutes ago, the comments contained a link to the wikipedia article [catenary ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary_ring). As that article makes clear, the catenary condition should be viewed as the weakest in a hierarchy of "smoothness" conditions on a ring, the strongest of which is the property of being a _regular_ ring. In his answer, Leo Alonso observes that these rings are in fact regular. So basically, the question asks "are these rings nice in a weak sense", and the answer is "yes, and don't worry -- they're actually nice in the strongest possible sense"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they are regular (the maximal ideal is generated by a number of elements equal to its dimension) and therefore Cohen-Macaulay (Matsumura, Theorem 17.8). And a Cohen Macaulay ring is catenary (Matsumura, Theorem 17.4).

Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, CUP, 1986